# AWS S3 grant access to single IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket and dedicated user for that bucket. How could I limit write access to this particular bucket for this dedicated user only and in the same time allow everyone else to read objects from S3?

Should I write a bucket policy for that? I am frustrated with primitive permissions I can configure from console and bucket policies. It seems like the same thing.

I started with such policy made via generator, but I am not sure it is correct.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1408967923699",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1408967189392",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1408967224662",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/bucket-user"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This looks about right. Do you see issues with this policy?

Comment: @TJ- I am about to test that. I blindly made this policy so I have no idea yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it with a group permission...you could just create a group with one user. In the Permissions section in S3 just make sure Everyone is allowed read access. In an IAM group to allow a user/group r/w access:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sidgoeshere",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was real simple via groups!

Comment: IAM is super handy once you start using it a lot.